# How we can calculate the Convolution Layer size in up-sampling using U-Net? like (w-f+2*p)/s +1 for upsampling 8x8 to 16x16

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

in deep learning U-net down sampling Formula is (w-k+2*p)/S +1 but here i have to calculate the up sampling formula suppose current layer size is 8x8x32 to next layer size 16X16x32 what will be the formula for this up-sampling calculation.

Answer (score 1):

The `Upsampling2D` is not the inverse of `MaxPooling`.

In fact, the max-pooling operation is non-invertible, meaning that there is no "opposite" mathematical operation which can lead us back to the state before applying the max-pooling.

Zeiler and Fergus state in their paper ["Visualizing and Understanding Convolutional Networks"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.2901.pdf):

> In the convnet, the max pooling operation is non-invertible, however
> we can obtain an approximate inverse by recording the locations of the
> maxima within each pooling region in a set of switch variables.

Indeed, an `Upsampling2D` layer with a kernel of 2x2 and a stride of 2 will double the size of the tensor, but that does not mean that `Upsampling2D` is the inverse of the `MaxPooling`.

For more information please read the article: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.2901.pdf and the TensorFlow documentation for it: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/UpSampling2D